# React Native Android TextInput placeholder style not completely updating

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to update the placeholder style of the TextInput component but on android its not completely updating the style.

It starts off with the correct style but once the text field is updated then cleared certain styles are not being applied. Like, fontWeight or fontFamily. However, fontSize is changing ?!

Here is my snak example: https://snack.expo.io/By2ijBW5X

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {textStyle: styles.textPlaceholder };
  }

  onChangeHandle = (txt) => {
    this.setState({ textStyle: txt.length > 0 ? styles.text : styles.textPlaceholder });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={this.state.textStyle}>Text Input</Text>
        <TextInput 
          onChangeText={this.onChangeHandle}
          placeholder='Enter Input Here'
          style={[{ height: 50, width: 200 }, this.state.textStyle]}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },

  text: {
    fontWeight: '900',
    fontSize: 20,
  },

  textPlaceholder: {
    fontWeight: '100',
    fontSize: 19,
 }
});
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? or know of a workaround?

Note: iOS is working correctly.

Comment: <Text style={this.state.textStyle}>Text Input</Text>
This line is causing the style change of the title text "Text input". I guess you don't want to update this section but the input field only?
https://snack.expo.io/S1NkfLbq7

Comment: Correct, this added style on the <Text> component was to illustrate what the <TextInput> style should be changing to.

If you run on Android you can see the thickness of font is changing for the <Text> but not the placeholder :(